# Finding element from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have following array of class names that i fetched from my css file

```
test array after printing values:

Array
(
  [0] => #sa_nav
  [1] => #sa_nav ul li.account
  [2] => .loyaltyBox
)
```

```php
 if(array_search("#sa_nav",$test))
 {
  echo 'Element is exist';
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'Element is not exist';
 }
```

though element exist in array it prints "Element not exist". plz help

Answer (score 4):

use `in_array` function

```
$test = array("#sa_nav", "#sa_nav ul li.account", ".loyaltyBox");

if (in_array("#sa_nav", $test)) {
  echo 'Element is exist';
} else {
  echo 'Element is not exist';
}
```

// Output

```
Element is exist
```

Comment: your code is working if array is initialize as 

$test = array("#sa_nav", "#sa_nav ul li.account", ".loyaltyBox");

but not for

    Array
(
  [0] => #sa_nav
  [1] => #sa_nav ul li.account
  [2] => .loyaltyBox
)

please help..

Comment: @MarkMartin you need to create custom function as in my answer..

Answer (score 2):

**What array_search do is searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful**

so that means it not returning true or false so use `in_array()` php function.

`in_array` — **Checks if a value exists in an array**

```
$test = array("#sa_nav","#sa_nav ul li.account",".loyaltyBox");

if(in_array("#sa_nav",$test))
{
  echo 'Element is exist';
}
else
{
  echo 'Element is not exist';
}
```

**For searching and returning TRUE FASLE**

```
function search_array($arrays, $cssSelector)
{
   foreach($arrays as $key => $array)
   {
      if ( $array === $cssSelector )
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

and call it as `search_array($array,'#sa_nav');`

Answer (score 2):

> [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) search for a value and returns the corresponding
>   key if it matches.

Now in your case -

#sa_nav key value is `0`

So going in the `IF` loop it evaluates something like this -

```
array_search("#sa_nav",$test) return value is `0` [Zero].
```

So the expression will be evaluated as  -

```
if(0)
```

so it outputs -

```
Element is not exist
```

No if you try with this code chunk, it is going to be evaluates as `true`

```
$test = array("#sa_nav","#sa_nav ul li.account",".loyaltyBox");

 if(array_search(".loyaltyBox",$test))
 {
  echo 'Element is exist';
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'Element is not exist';
 }
```

to make your code piece working you can try with `in_array()` method as suggested in most other answers.

Answer (score 1):

The manual is always the first place to look:

> [**`array_search`**](http://www.php.net/array_search)
>
> Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.
>
> ***Warning***
>
> ***This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.***

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
$test = array("#sa_nav","#sa_nav ul li.account",".loyaltyBox");

 if(in_array("#sa_nav",$test))
 {
  echo 'Element is exist';
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'Element is not exist';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Php inbuilt function

[array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the corresponding key if successful](http://www.php.net/array_search)

Or You can also use

[in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: i have checked for both array_search & in_array it displays same result 

Element not exist...

Comment: @MarkMartin Can you please provide me the code snipet

Comment: Array
(
  [0] => #sa_nav
  [1] => #sa_nav ul li.account
  [2] => .loyaltyBox
)

This is my array result when i print_r() array & i want to search #sa_nav is exist in my array result or not ...

Comment: @MarkMartin Please checkout here http://codepad.org/SK9MrJAz

Comment: @MarkMartin Did you checked that, Working ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you phrase a question like this, considering using `var_dump()` to show what your array comprises.

Secondly, a simple change in your condition should do it:

```
if (false !== array_search("#sa_nav",$test)) {
}
```

If `#sa_nav` is the first item, `array_search()` would return `0`, which evaluates as `false`.  Considering that you're not really using the return value of `array_search()` in any particularly meaningful way you could also use `in_array()` which always returns a boolean instead.